# A strange behaviour regarding filtering a dataframe based on the datatime column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, timedelta

I have a strange situation with the code below. As you see there seem to be no data with **timestamp_day** value smaller than the indicated value in the code below:

```
print myDF.shape
> (447609, 20)

print myDF[myDF['timestamp_day'] < timedelta(2014, 7, 26, 2, 0)].shape
> (0, 20)
```

However, when I check the minimum value of **timestamp_day** (see below), I see that the code above should return some rows.

```
myDF['timestamp_day'].min()
> datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 21, 12, 0)
```

Anyone has any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: hmm, `timedelta` and `datetime` objects are not the same. `from datetime import datetime, timedelta ; d = datetime(1970, 1, 1) ; t = timedelta(1970, 1, 1) ; print(d == t) ; # False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pulling out a few practice values to test if your inequality makes sense.

```
datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 21, 12, 0) < timedelta(2014, 7, 26, 2, 0)
TypeError: unorderable types: datetime.datetime() < datetime.timedelta()
```

have you tried just a datetime.datetime to compare against?

```
datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 21, 12, 0) < datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 26, 2, 0)
True
```